# get file modification time

Tags: java

i want to write a code for monitoring file changes and reacting to changes.
so i write a TimerTask to periodically check the modification of file
but i have a problem:
when file is open by other programs such as excel or word and i'm closing the file
without any changes,value  File.lastModified() is changing.
i am also trying to get modification date by running dir shell script, it's work fine but
it only has minute accuracy!
can any one help me?
thanks

Comment: I think (not sure, just think) .... is it possible that Excel or Word ACTUALLY modify the file?

Comment: [[Sorry for posting two comments mistakenly]] Perhaps you can compare the file before and after access by Excel or Word and we can really see if there is any modification or not.

Comment: no excel and word does not modify the file because the modification date of file as shown by windows does not change

Answer (score 2):

Word and Excel write your user name into the file when you open it (so other users can see who is working on it when they try to open the file). So it's correct that `File.lastModified()` is changing.

On Windows, there is no command line tool which can show you the modification time in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the behavior you describe, using OpenOffice under Windows.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CsvWriter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "test.xls";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        out.println("a,b,c,d");
        out.println("e,f,g,h");
        out.println("i,j,k,l");
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Before: " + new Date(file.lastModified()));

    // manual steps:    
        // open test.xls with OpenOffice
        // close test.xls
    // press enter

    System.in.read(); // wait until 'enter' is pressed

        System.out.println("After: " + new Date(file.lastModified()));
    }
}
```

output:

```
Before: Mon Oct 05 10:01:27 CEST 2009

After: Mon Oct 05 10:01:27 CEST 2009
```

Maybe you could post some code showing how you are doing it? And on what platform are you running your application?

Comment: long newModifiedTime = file.exists() ? file.lastModified() : -1;
             if (newModifiedTime != lastModified&&!isOpen)
             {
                 if(listener!=null){
                  listener.fileModified(this);
                 }
             }

this is part of my code 
i am using windows 2003 server and jdk1.6

Answer (score 0):

If you want accurate times in Windows environment, have a look at this:

[WinAPI FILETIME structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> Not all file systems can record creation and last access time and not all file systems record them in the same manner. For example, on NT FAT, create time has a resolution of 10 milliseconds, write time has a resolution of 2 seconds, and access time has a resolution of 1 day (really, the access date). On NTFS, access time has a resolution of 1 hour. Therefore, the GetFileTime function may not return the same file time information set using the SetFileTime function. Furthermore, FAT records times on disk in local time. However, NTFS records times on disk in UTC. For more information, see File Times.